# Python - rsync over ssh [ how to enter password ]

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync

I have a problem with rsync over SSH. I mean the way of entering a password. I can't enter it immediately after entering the line:

```
$ rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/
```

and i have no idea how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: what has this to do with python or pyqt? either remove the tags, or please explain what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Is the problem you don't want to have your password in plain text in the script, or the mechanics of the python shell interface?

Comment: They made it hard to do what you want because it's a bad (insecure) idea.

Comment: I am going to take a guess, and say use SSH keys.

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
eval  `keychain --eval id_rsa`  #Or  id_dsa / whatever you key is called
```

In your `.bash_profile` and log in to a terminal some ware. (Or you could just run it plain)

Then stick it in you script (you will have to run it onesome ware else as stated before unless your script is interactive)

You will need to install keychain and read a tutorial on making keys with ssh-keygen beforehand.

This is a rough answer for a rough question.